# Redirect to origin page that requested the login in Laravel

Tags: laravel, redirect, laravel-5.8

I have searched all over the place, none of the answers was to my needs.

I have a Laravel app, with various pages that require the user to be logged in.

The normal redirect in Laravel after login is to the home page.

How can I make a redirect to the original page that requested the login?

For example:

A user tries to go to `example.com/page/1` that is for authenticated users only. He is redirected to the login page, submit the form and then redirects to the home page. How can I redirect him back to `example.com/page/1` or whatever page that he came from?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could potentially hook in to Laravel's `intended()` method. Usually, this would be a guarded route that a user tried to access before they were redirected to the login page but you can manually set it to what ever you want it to be.

In your `LoginController` add the following:

```
public function showLoginForm()
{
    if (!session()->has('url.intended')) {
        redirect()->setIntendedUrl(session()->previousUrl());
    }

    return view('auth.login');
}
```

This will check to see if the intended url is set, if it isn't it will set it to the previous url.

Comment: This is the solution i used that is working as i wanted. Thank you.

Answer (score 3):

You can use [intended](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/authentication) method for this purpose, From the docs:

> The intended method on the redirector will redirect the user to the
>   URL they were attempting to access before being intercepted by the
>   authentication middleware. A fallback URI may be given to this method
>   in case the intended destination is not available.

In your Login Controller add the below code:

```
public function authenticate(Request $request)
{
    $credentials = $request->only('email', 'password');

    if (Auth::attempt($credentials)) {
        // Authentication passed...
        return redirect()->intended('dashboard');
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

in your **LoginController** :

```
protected function authenticated(Request $request, $user) {
       return redirect()->back();
}
```